# How can I copy artifact from artifactory to a remote server in Jenkins with out plugins?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am new to Jenkins and the DevOps world. I have created a Jenkins Maven project job that creates jar and pushes the artifact to jFrog. My next step is to download that artifact to my server where I need to execute that jar.

I got Publish over SSH plugin which is some how not allowed to use. I need to do it as a post build step using scripting. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you check the [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)?

Comment: You will be able to simply download a file from Artifactory using e.g. wget. Not sure whether this would an option for you as of course you would need to know the URL.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I managed to do this in a two step process.

First I use `curl` to download the *Jar* from *Artifactory*.  Then second I upload it using `scp`.

Please let me know if any one have better way to do it.

Download step:

```
curl -u  admin:root http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myRepo/diman/com/test/0.0.1/myJar-0.0.1.jar -o myJar-0.0.1.jar
```

Upload step:

```
scp myJar-0.0.1.jar user@myproject.diman.com:~
```

Though this will work only if push is allowed to target server.

Thanks.